# Android or web app to track habit adoption

Tags: android, web-apps, productivity

I'm starting with ZTD, so I need to adopt some new habits.

I am looking for an app in which I can keep track if I made the habit that day and set up rewards at some points in the calendar, that will be rewarded if I kept the habit until that day.

Do you know any app that can be used to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HabitBull is really nice and should have everything you need. It's available both for Android and for IOS (http://www.habitbull.com).

Comment: I'm giving it a try and it seems to fit my needs very well.